# In Visual Studio 2010, how do I quickly switch from a .h file to the corresponding .cpp file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a shortcut to move between header and source file in VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602682/is-there-a-shortcut-to-move-between-header-and-source-file-in-vc)

How can I easily toggle between a `.h` file and its corresponding `.cpp` file?

Visual Studio provides **half** the solution: if I am working in `myfile.cpp`, I can right-click and choose “Go To Header File.” But if I have the header file open, there’s no easy way to switch to the corresponding `.cpp` file.

What would be even easier is a button, similar to the “Go to Counterpart” button in Xcode, that just toggles between the `.h` and `.cpp`.

There must be an extension for this, but I haven’t found it.

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602682/is-there-a-shortcut-to-move-between-header-and-source-file-in-vc which has a link to a more elaborate macro http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=8146