# How to arrange C++ solution document tabs in pairs of h and cpp?

Tags: visual-studio, navigation, header-files

When I am writing C++ code in Visual Studio 2017 solution view with tabbed documents (which, as far as I can tell, is the standard setting for vcxproj projects after a default installation), I frequently create a mess of 10 or more tabs in opening order. While the tabs' context menu has become quite sophisticated over the years, IMO it lacks some arrangement options, especially one which I miss a lot:

When I have a header file open, I can nicely find the source folder it is located in, by clicking the solution explorer's "sync with active document" arrows icon. I then frequently find myself wanting to open the corresponding cpp file in the vicinity of the h file I just came from. This then opens in a new tab on the far right. Is there a way to force Visual Studio to always arrange corresponding h/cpp tab pairs next to each other? Alphabetically sorting by file name would already do the trick in 99% of cases. The dropdown next to the tabs presents them in that order, why not the tabs themselves?

[image]

I looked in the Tools→Options dialog, and into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602682/1132334) and [this](http://www.alteridem.net/2008/02/26/visual-studio-macro-to-switch-between-cpp-and-h-files/); while similar, not quite what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine h and cpp tabs together and quickly switch between them with my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension:

[image]

Comment: I've been very happy with Tab Studio, but right now it just won't group a CPP and H file into one tab. I don't even see it as an option in the settings. I'm guessing I should uninstall and reinstall the extension?

Comment: @aalimian Yes, it may help if something is wrong with installation.

Comment: actually everything was fine with Tab Studio, I just had to check a setting to group CPP and H files regardless of their paths. 